# Debounce function in react js functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debouncing

I tried to implement the debounce functionality in the react functional component. But due to some reason, it is not working.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [random, setRandom] = React.useState(Math.random());
  const changeKey = () => {
    setRandom(Math.random());
  };

  const debounce = (func, timeout = 1000) => {
    let timer;
    return (...args) => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        func.apply(this, args);
      }, timeout);
    };
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          debounce(changeKey(), 2000);
        }}
      >
        <p>Click Me!</p>
      </button>
      {random}
    </div>
  );
}
```

here I have added the codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-silence-6i532c?file=/src/App.js:0-857

Answer (score 0):

Consider implementing it with a hook. This one, `useDebounce` from `react-use` is very good. https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useDebounce.md

Comment: I just want to know, what i have done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your debounce function is returning a function. So you need to run the function. Also you add unnecessary {} for calling debounce.

I mean change:

```
 onClick={() => {
          debounce(changeKey(), 2000);
        }}
```

to:

```
onClick={debounce(changeKey, 2000)}
```

Complete code:

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [random, setRandom] = React.useState(0);
  const changeKey = () => {
    setRandom(Math.random());
  };

  const debounce = (func, timeout = 1000) => {
    let timer;
    return (...args) => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        func.apply(this, args);
      }, timeout);
    };
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={() => debounce(changeKey, 2000)()}>
        <p>Click Me!</p>
      </button>
      {random}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note: It's better to define your debounce in another file and call it with useCallback.

Answer (score 0):

The main changes are here:

```
const debouncedChangeKey = useCallback(debounce(changeKey, 2000), [changeKey]);
```

And here:

```xml
<button onClick={debouncedChangeKey}>
```

Also, your `debounce` function should not be defined within the scope of the component. It should exist outside of the component on its own.

### Working examples

Here is the correct layout for debounce usage.

**Note:** Refer to the comments in the code below for an explanation.

```js
const { useCallback, useState} = React;

// Defined outside component
const debounce = (func, timeout = 1000) => {
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => func(...args), timeout);
  };
};

function App() {
  const [randomKey, setRandomKey] = useState(Math.random());
  
  // Normal event handler function with event
  const changeKey = useCallback((e) => {
    console.log(e.type); // click
    setRandomKey(Math.random());
  }, []);
  
  // debouncedChangeKey = debounce(changeKey, 2000)
  const debouncedChangeKey = useCallback(debounce(changeKey, 2000), [changeKey]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={debouncedChangeKey}>{/* <-- just pass it in */}
        <p>Click Me!</p>
      </button>
      {randomKey}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
  .render(<App />);
```

```css
button {
  margin-right: 1rem; /* Push the random key over a bit */
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why was useCallback used twice?  Why not just put this?
useCallback(debounce( () => setRandomKey(Math.random(), 2000),  [changeKey]);

Comment: @Luis to separate the original handler from the debounced version. The callback will only be initialized once, unless any of the dependencies are changed. I could have done that, but it was for separation of concerns.